# ASP.NET Core View - creating dropdown filter for single column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET CORE app.

In one of my views I have `Status` column among others which can have 2 possible values: `Active` or `Deactivated`.
How can I create filter on that column with simple drop-list that would allow me to filter whole table based on these 2 column values?

All I can find are lengthy tutorials that are not quite covering what I need.
Basically I need someone to give me few links or points me on how to implement this in most simple way.

**EDIT**

column definition in Model:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "BIT")]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }
```

So in my Index View I have:

```
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
....
         <td>
             @(item.Status ? "Active" : "Deactivated")
         </td>
```

How can I turn that header title into title with drop-down list?
Something like this:

[image]

Obviously in my case instead of "Company Name" column name would be "Status" and in drop-down values I would have only 2 items - "Active" and "Deactivated".

Comment: just add a filter in your controller based on the value of the pulldown.. so  IQueryable<Item> Items= _context.Items; ...then if (StatusFilter=="Active") { Items=Items.Where(i=>i.Status=="Active"); }

Comment: @pcalkins could you explain what "StatusFilter" should be?

Comment: You could have a link/toggle (<a href="/page?StatusFilter=Active&...> or <a asp-for-StatusFilter...>) for that, or a pulldown.  Depends on what you want.  Then bind that value in the controller.

Comment: it'd be similar to taking a search parameter.  Maybe include the code you've tried or are currently working with and I can be more specific.  (the .cs and .cshtml file)

Comment: @pcalkins I've edited. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: @pcalkins I've added explanation about how header suppose to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a test based on your needs, below is a working demo:

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Active",
        Value = "Active"
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Deactivated",
        Value = "Deactivated"
    });
}

<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("Status", listItems, "Status")
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(item.Status ? "Active" : "Deactivated")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("#Status").on('change', function () {
            var val = $("#Status option:selected").text();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '/Home/FilterByStatus',
                data: { status: val },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#mytable tbody").empty();
                    $.each(result, function (i, value) {
                        $("#mytable tbody").append("<tr><td>" + value.id + "</td><td>" +
                            value.name + "</td><td>" + (value.status ? "Active" : "Deactivated") +"</td></tr>")
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    
    </script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public static List<Product> products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product{ Id = 1, Name = "AA", Status = true},
    new Product{ Id = 2, Name = "BB", Status = true},
    new Product{ Id = 3, Name = "CC", Status = false},
    new Product{ Id = 4, Name = "DD", Status = false}
};

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(products);
}

public IActionResult FilterByStatus(string status)
{
    var filterproducts = products.ToList();
    if (status == "Active")
    {
        filterproducts = products.Where(p => p.Status == true).ToList();
        return Json(filterproducts);
    }
    else if(status == "Deactivated")
    {
        filterproducts = products.Where(p => p.Status == false).ToList();
        return Json(filterproducts);
    }
    return Json(filterproducts);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Let me check, give me a time to implement this.  if this is working I'm giving you +everything. Thank you!