# OrderBy in EF Core sort all columns

Tags: asp.net-core, sorting, entity-framework-core, sql-order-by, filtering

This `thead` contains all the columns of the `Product` model. I want to apply the filter only to `Title` column. But I don't know why the `OrderBy` method in the controller, apply the filter for all the properties of Product model.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">
            <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["TitleSortParam"]">Title</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">ISBN</th>
        <th scope="col">List Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Author</th>
        <th scope="col">Category</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
public IActionResult Index([FromQuery] int? tableLength, string? sortOrder)
{
    ViewData["TitleSortParam"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "title_desc" : "";

    IEnumerable<Product> objProductList =
    _unitOfWork.ProductRepo.GetAll (null, includeProperties: "Category", takeEntities: tableLength);

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "title_desc":
            objProductList = objProductList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Title);
            break;
    }

    return View(objProductList.ToList());
}
```

This is the `GetAll()` method:

For more info, here I applied the possibility to add AsNoTracking, to add a condition with the Where() method, if you want to include with the Include() some property of the model etc.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>>? filter = null,
            string? includeProperties = null,
            bool enableAsNoTracking = false,
            int? takeEntities = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;

    if (enableAsNoTracking)
    {
        query = query.AsNoTracking();
    }

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperties))
    {
        foreach (var property in includeProperties
                                     .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(property);
        }
    }

    if (takeEntities != null && takeEntities > 0)
    {
        query = query.Take((int)takeEntities);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` sorts the rows, not the columns. Can you show an example of what you get and what you expect?

Comment: Also I don't see the relation between what you posted in HTML and the EF-query. EF queries a database, not HTML.

Comment: "I want to apply the filter only to Title column. " You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922808/asp-net-core-view-creating-dropdown-filter-for-single-column). Maybe it's useful to filter for single column.

Answer (score 1):

Code like that is broken in a number of ways and should not be used. One big problem which may explain what you are seeing is that you have a `Take` being applied *before* a sorting.  `Take` should only be applied *after* sorting, otherwise you are just sorting records that the `Take` has selected arbitrarily which will depend on the Database Server paging.

My advice is ***don't*** try and abstract away the DbContext with methods like "GetAll" and then duplicating the effort on how to do filtering, eager loading, pagination, etc. etc. etc. DbSets and their `IQueryable` implementation already do this. Then just make sure your sorting is being done prior to your pagination. (`Skip` and `Take`)